# SAS or Postgresql:add column value according to another column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sas

I want to add a column "index" and the value for column "index" are same when the rows have same value in column "variable".You can use Postgresql or SAS syntax.

One thing is the values in column "variable" is changing each day，like tableA and tableB,so hard code is not acceptable.any advice is appreciated!

```
+----------+--------------+------+-------+-----+-----+-------+
| variable | new_variable | type | start | end | woe | index |
+----------+--------------+------+-------+-----+-----+-------+
| A        | mi_A         | char | 1     |     | 1.3 |     1 |
| A        | mi_A         | char | 0     |     | 0.6 |     1 |
| B        | mi_B         | char | 1     |     | 5.4 |     2 |
| B        | mi_B         | char | 0     |     | 0.1 |     2 |
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | 3     |     | 1.3 |     3 |
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | @0    |     | 0.6 |     3 |
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | 2     |     | 5.4 |     3 |
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | N     |     | 0.1 |     3 |
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | 1     |     | 1.3 |     3 |
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | 99    |     | 0.6 |     3 |
| mar_sign | mar_sign     | char | 0     |     | 5.4 |     4 |
| mar_sign | mar_sign     | char | Y     |     | 0.1 |     4 |
| mar_sign | mar_sign     | char | N     |     |   6 |     4 |
| C        | C            | char | 6     |     |   2 |     5 |
| C        | C            | char | 7     |     | 2.1 |     5 |
| C        | C            | char | 8     |     | 2.2 |     5 |
+----------+--------------+------+-------+-----+-----+-------+
                         (tableA)

+--------------+--------------+------+-------+-----+-----+-------+
|   variable   | new_variable | type | start | end | woe | index |
+--------------+--------------+------+-------+-----+-----+-------+
| D            | mi_D         | char | 1     |     |   1 |     1 |
| D            | mi_D         | char | 0     |     |   2 |     1 |
| E            | mi_E         | char | 1     |     |   2 |     2 |
| E            | mi_E         | char | 0     |     |   3 |     2 |
| education_bg | education_bg | char | 3     |     |   1 |     3 |
| education_bg | education_bg | char | @0    |     |   5 |     3 |
| education_bg | education_bg | char | 2     |     |   6 |     3 |
| education_bg | education_bg | char | N     |     |   4 |     3 |
| education_bg | education_bg | char | 1     |     |   3 |     3 |
| education_bg | education_bg | char | 99    |     |   3 |     3 |
| sex          | sex          | char | 0     |     |   2 |     4 |
| sex          | sex          | char | Y     |     |   1 |     4 |
| sex          | sex          | char | N     |     |   0 |     4 |
| C            | C            | char | 6     |     |   6 |     5 |
| C            | C            | char | 7     |     |   4 |     5 |
| C            | C            | char | 8     |     |   1 |     5 |
+--------------+--------------+------+-------+-----+-----+-------+
                             (tableB)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in SAS in a single datastep using the Retain Functionality and grouping by the variable.

Code:

```
data have;
infile datalines dlm='|';
input variable $ new_variable $ type $ start $  end $ woe ;
datalines;
| A        | mi_A         | char | 1     |     | 1.3 
| A        | mi_A         | char | 0     |     | 0.6 
| B        | mi_B         | char | 1     |     | 5.4 
| B        | mi_B         | char | 0     |     | 0.1 
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | 3     |     | 1.3 
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | @0    |     | 0.6 
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | 2     |     | 5.4 
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | N     |     | 0.1 
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | 1     |     | 1.3 
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | 99    |     | 0.6 
| mar_sign | mar_sign     | char | 0     |     | 5.4 
| mar_sign | mar_sign     | char | Y     |     | 0.1 
| mar_sign | mar_sign     | char | N     |     |   6 
| C        | C            | char | 6     |     |   2 
| C        | C            | char | 7     |     | 2.1 
| C        | C            | char | 8     |     | 2.2  
run;

data want;
set have ;
by variable notsorted;
retain index;
if first.variable then index+1;
run;
```

Note: I created the index and only increment its value with new group value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table that is something like:

```
    select distinct variable, montonic() as newindex from mydata order by index;
```

And then join it back onto the the original table.  You can do it all in one step, as a matter of fact:

```
    select a.variable, a.new_variable, a.type, a.start, a.end, a.woe, b.newindex as index from mydata as a left join (select distinct variable, montonic() as newindex from my table order by index) as b on  a.variable=b.variable;
```

Or something along these lines.  I can't say that I 100% understood what you were trying to achieve, but maybe this helps.

Please note that the monotonic() function in SAS is still (I believe) undocumented.  All that means is that SAS may or may not continue to include it.  It works, but maybe they consider it experimental or something.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Postgres' [`dense_rank`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-window.html) window function for ranking without gaps:

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY variable) as "index"
FROM mytable
```

[Rextester demo](http://rextester.com/WWPHCD32559) *(with random, seeded data)*